# selectable look-up table using pre-processor define

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor, lookup-tables

I have a c program that uses a look-up table defined in a separate .c file.

The c program is actually run on a PIC24H and compiled using the MPLAB XC16 compiler.  That's not particularly relevant except it provides motivation for what I'm trying to do.

I would like to have several look-up tables, each in their own .c file.  I would then like to use the pre-processor to define which table gets loaded into the program code.

I'm unsure if unused tables all in the same .c file would take up program space, or if the compiler would ignore them.

If all tables were stored in the program code, this would take up precious program memory.

Mainly I'm looking for advice on the mechanics of implementing the selective look-up.  I'm thinking of below, but not sure how that would actually work.

```
#define CLEVEL 75 // CLEVEL may be in set {45 60 75}

#if (CLEVEL==45}
#include "clevel45.h"
#elseif (CLEVEL==60}
#include "clevel60.h"
#elseif (CLEVEL==75)
#include "clevel75.h"
#endif
```

Comment: The other solution is to put all three tables into a single .c file, and use preprocessor directives to select the table.

Comment: If these boil down to the same variable they should definitely not be in separate files, but in one single .c file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mix files which could not exist in the future, creating useless dependences. Another way:

your_cfg_file.h:

```
#define CLEVEL75
```

your_clevel75_file.h:

```
#ifdef CLEVEL75
{your parameters}
#endif
```

your_clevel60_file.h:

```
#ifdef CLEVEL60
{your parameters}
#endif
```

...and so on...

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying it the way you describe, and I'm getting an undefined reference error, even though it's clear the precompiler would trigger on one of the ifdefs.  The undefined reference is inside those ifdefs.

Comment: Show us your new code. You might have missed something.

Answer (score 2):

Or try something like this:

level.c

```
#define CLEVEL 75 // CLEVEL may be in set {45 60 75}

#if (CLEVEL==45}
/*
parameter for level 45 ...
*/    

#elseif (CLEVEL==60}
/*
parameter for level 60 ...
*/    

#elseif (CLEVEL==75)
/*
parameter for level 75 ...
*/    

#endif
```

In this way you don't have any unused header files,